# How to retrieve current extents of the location?

Tags: google-maps, cartography, extents, select-by-location

How google is getting its maps zoom to current extents where we have located eg: If i am get hyderabad kphp on google maps its directly redirects to hyderabad city extents while opening a map , if it is chennai the if i open google maps in chennai the city extents automatically changes do it goes ? Is it based on IP address location or what?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in this matter but I researched the topic and it turns out that there are several ways a website or a browser tracks our physical location like IP address, HTTP referrer, cookies etc. See this link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/115483/htg-explains-learn-how-websites-are-tracking-you-online/
Google maps estimates your location from your browser's location information.
You can even turn off the location information in your browser:
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&authuser=0&p=newmaps_mylocation&rd=2